# Facebook Messenger does not appear automatically when visiting the facebook page

Tags: facebook

I have included a chatbot on my facebook business page. Now if I click on the "Send Message" button of the site it will open the Messenger window and I can start the conversation and chat with the bot.

However, my goal is that when I visit the page the Messenger window will open automatically. Therefore I have changed in the Settings > Messaging of the business page the "Response time" to immediately and "Show a Messenger Greeting" to Yes. Further options are not activated.

Unfortunately the messenger window will not be opened automatically when one visits the facebook business page.

Any ideas what else I can try to fix this problem?

Comment: Is your bot still in development, or live and fully approved in Facebook review yet?

Comment: it is already fully approved by Facebook